# node kriskowal/q promise stack errors on chaining promises

Tags: node.js, q

The following code errors out on the first .then with:

```
/Users/danielbyrne/working/mite_npm/mite.js:48
      .then(configMan.validateSettings(parsedData))
ReferenceError: parsedData is not defined
```

I don't understand why this code is failing.
The call:

```
parseConfigurationFile(path.join(__dirname,'file.config'))
        .then(validateSettings(parsedData));
```

The functions it calls:

```
function parseConfigurationFile(fileName) {
    var readFile = q.nfbind(fs.readFile);   

    readFile(fileName,"utf-8")
    .then(function(data) {      
        var deferred = q.defer();        
        // Return the Config 'settings' in JSON
        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        return deferred.promise;    
    });         
}

function vaidateSettings (data) {...}
```

The only way this works is if I change the function validateSettings to an anonymous function and place it inline like this :

```
parseConfigurationFile(path.join(__dirname,'file.config'))
        .then(function(parsedData){...});
```

Why can i not chain named functions in this manner?

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? This is definitely a case where `data` is a variable somewhere in your code, mine, or possibly someone else’s is used but does not exist in that scope. I’ve checked Q and there are no references to `data` in that library.

Comment: I apologize. The 'parsedData' referenced is on line 2 of the example.

Comment: I've tried refactoring this code several different ways. Basically the second .then always throws this error unless it is an anonymous function.  I'm sure it's just because I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: The value returned from parseConfigurationFile() is not available to the second function call validateSettings() unless I make it an anonymous function.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validateSettings call should be like this:

```
parseConfigurationFile(path.join(__dirname,'file.config'))
    .then(validateSettings);
```

The reason is that the validateSettings needs to be referenced as a function and the .then will invoke that function with the correct parameter.  Doing it the way you are doing it, you receive a reference error because parsedData is not available at the time the function call is bound.